# connect two separate computers using bluetooth

Tags: ros, bluetooth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I have been fighting with this for the past 2 days now. I have two separate computers, each running Ubuntu of course, and each has its own bluetooth dongle (same make and model). I can get each of the computers to bond to one another, but when I try to telnet via Putty or any other means I get the following error:

> Connection Refused

(#via Putty)

or

> Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused

(#via rfcomm in the terminal)

To give you a bit more info., I have also tried to connect each computer using ssh over WLAN. However, I get the following error:

> ssh: connect to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection refused

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11877/connect-two-separate-computers-using-bluetooth/) by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, I figured out how to manually get the rfcomm0 by doing the following:

> cd /dev

> sudo mknod --mode 600 /dev/rfcomm0 c 216 0

Then I uncommented the following lines in my /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf file:

> rfcomm0 {

```
      bind yes; #set no to yes if it is not already set
```

> 

```
      device <bdaddr>; #where bdaddr is the address of the bluetooth with which you are trying to bind
```

> 

```
      channel 1; #I think any channel will do
```

> 

```
      comment "Add whatever you want here";
```

> }

I'm not sure as to whether or not I needed to do the first portion once I uncommented the rfcomm0 stuff, but it worked nonetheless.  Once I had that bit working, I tried your command Bemfica along with a sudo rfcomm -a to check the connection.  Finally, I transferred a file by typing: bluetooth-sendto .  So, it looks like I'm at least moving in the right direction.  I'll be back with more questions/answers.

---

Originally posted by [dougnets22](https://answers.ros.org/users/1349/dougnets22/) with karma: 61 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on 2011-11-11**:
you should edit your question putting the resolution you found instead of post an answer